# What is the affiliation between this site and Strange Works?

Tags: discussion, site-design, site-promotion

I have seen the title `SPONSORED BY STRANGE WORKS`. What/How exactly are they sponsoring? Is the person who opened the proposal for this site affiliated with `STRANGE WORKS`?

Comment: Related:  ["Why does the Quantum Computing site look different?"](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-does-the-quantum-computing-site-look-different).

Comment: @Nat I would even say it is a duplicate.

Comment: @MEE I see the part about sponsors, but I don’t see the direct mention of STRANGE WORKS or it’s affiliation with the person who created to open this site.

Comment: @Riz-waan this [blog article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/27/quantum-computing-site-launches-with-the-help-of-strangeworks/) can give your more information how site sponsorship works. || This site has launched shortly before it would have launched  if the normal area51 process had completed so there has not been made that kind of large exception.

Comment: @MEE That blog does help, thanks.