# Jobs in Quantum Computing

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Stack Overflow has a [jobs page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/get-started). Would that be possible to implement here?

If yes, awesome! If no, alternative suggestions?

Comment: Alternative suggestions on how to find a job as a quantum computing researcher?

Comment: Yes! Or on how to find people to hire.

Comment: Definitely a good idea, but the problem (as of now) is that there are very very few industry *jobs* in "quantum computing", unlike software jobs.

Comment: A Jobs page won't be possible but [other possibilities](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/23) might be. A couple of the possibilities (community or sponsored ads) might require a tiny 'change in functionality' that wouldn't *normally* happen on beta sites. However, this site is different (we're sponsored) which means that, in principle, it might be possible to have either of these enabled earlier than normal, as per [this post](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/23)

Comment: Since [Jobs was sunset](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/1328704) about a year ago, I'm declining this.