# A "jobs" page for quantum computing - suggestions

Tags: discussion

Recently, there was a meta post called [Jobs in Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254/jobs-in-quantum-computing). The mods are interested in this (and the post got a few upvotes), and we wonder if you guys are too. To get some ideas for the community, we talked to the community mods and got two options:

1. A meta post, where companies/researchers post what are normally answers, but in this case are ads.
2. We request for community ads to get set up, which companies/researchers can create and post for the community.

All of this is moot, of course, if the community doesn't want any sort of job listing on here. What do you all think?

Comment: It might also be possible to get sponsored ads set up

Comment: Awesome! I also had been considering a meta post. Excited to see some movement on this.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like the idea of **getting community ads set up**. To be clear, I'm suggesting we go for option 2 on the list in the question.

As community ads are decided by the community by upvoting answers to a meta post, this also means that there would be a meta post that includes job ads, although this post would also include links that aren't job ads.

An extra advantage of this is that we would be able to link to some useful places, such as other SE sites (physics, maths, math overflow, computer science and theoretical computer science come to mind) as well as sites outside the SE network that are useful for quantum computing, such as IBM's quantum experience, Microsoft's Q# guide and the quantum algorithm zoo, *if* the community wants those links.

From a slightly broader perspective, we've already got community ads on (at least some of) those SE sites, so I feel that it's only fair that we give them the same potential opportunity (or at least, as much as we can, considering some of them get vast amounts more traffic than we  get here).

Comment: In my opinion, yes, we need the community ads as soon as possible, but let us not mix this up with the "job-listing" idea

Comment: @Blue Community ads *is* an option for the job listing idea - once we get community ads set up, job ads can be posted as a potential community ad. To be clear, I'm suggesting option 2 in the question

Comment: @Blue A specialised search bar or specific job page isn't possible at the moment (we've already asked). So, that leaves us with the options in the question (meta post, community or sponsored ads, or no job ads at all), unless someone has a better idea, which can be implemented with negligible dev effort

Comment: @Blue If you want job ads and think that's the best solution, could you maybe put that in an answer? We need to figure out what people want (if anything) somehow!